# display image after after on the panel with a time gap

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Video implements ActionListener
{
    static int width=480;
    static int height=368;
    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    static JButton button = new JButton("Submit");
    static BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage((int) (width), (int) (height), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    static BufferedImage img1[] = new BufferedImage[60];
    static {
      for (int i = 0; i < img1.length; i++) {
        img1[i] = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
      }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Video V1 = new Video();
        String fileName = args[0];
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);

            long len = file.length();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)len];
            int offset = 0;
            int numRead = 0;
            int ind =0;
            int[][] pixarray=new int[height+100][width+100];
            int[][] red=new int[width*2][height*2];
            int[][] green=new int[width*2][height*2];
            int[][] blue=new int[width*2][height*2];
            while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
                offset += numRead;
            }
            for(int frames=0;frames<60;frames++)
            {
                ind=height*width*frames*3;
                   for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
                {
                       for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
                       {
                           byte a = 0;
                           byte r = bytes[ind];
                           byte g = bytes[ind+height*width];
                           byte b = bytes[ind+height*width*2];
                           int pix = 0xff000000 | ((r & 0xff) << 16) | ((g & 0xff) << 8) | (b & 0xff);
                           pixarray[y][x]=pix;
                           red[y][x] = (pix >>> 16) & 0xff;
                           green[y][x] = (pix >>> 8) & 0xff;
                           blue[y][x] = pix & 0xff;
                           img1[frames].setRGB(x,y,pix);
                           ind++;
                       }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }


        JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img1[50]));

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //frame.setSize(200,100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
       // Button button = new Button("Submit");
       // frame.add(button);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        button.addActionListener(V1);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("1");
        for(int i=0;i<img1.length;i++)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(img1.length);
         }


    }
}
```

Is my code. My img1 is an array of frames. in this instance my video has 60 frames.

I wanna add each frame to my panel with a time gap. i am unable to do it because every time i add it to the panel in my `ActionEvent` its acting weird. help me out please.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Swing Timer (not a TimerTask). When the Timer fires the code will execute in the EDT so you can safely reset the icon of your JLabel. So I would first create ImageIcons from your BufferedImages and store the Icons in your array.

Read the secton from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Timers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information. You may also want to check out the section on Concurreny to understand why executing code in the EDT is important.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TimerTask

```
class VideoTask extends TimerTask {
   private Frame frame;
   private int frameId;
   public void run() {
     frame.drawImage(....);
     frameId++;
   }
}
```

And in the action listener for the button - schedule the task:

```
VideoTask videoTask = new VideoTask(frame);
videoTask.schedule(..);
```